# Isolating the error message in error handling from Salesforce API

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, error-handling, salesforce

I am trying to query objects in `Salesforce` using the library `simple_salesforce`. If the query is not valid, I get a `traceback` error, which I've been able to isolate with a `try, except` statement. In this example, Contactd is not a real table to query. I would really like to just isolate the error message itself, but e is a class instance so I'm not sure how to isolate.

My Code:

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce

sf = Salesforce(username='',
                password='',
                security_token='',
                sandbox='')

try:

    print sf.query_all("SELECT Id FROM Contactd")
except Exception as e:
    print type(e)
    print e
```

Output:

```
<class 'simple_salesforce.api.SalesforceMalformedRequest'>
Malformed request https://cs42.salesforce.com/services/data/v29.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id+FROM+Contactd. Response content: [{u'errorCode': u'INVALID_TYPE', u'message': u"\nSELECT Id FROM Contactd\n               ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:16\nsObject type 'Contactd' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names."}]
```

Desired Output:

```
\nSELECT Id FROM Contactd\n               ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:16\nsObject type 'Contactd' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names."
```

Also included is the `simple_salesforce` error handling code:

```
def _exception_handler(result, name=""):
    """Exception router. Determines which error to raise for bad results"""
    try:
        response_content = result.json()
    except Exception:
        response_content = result.text

    exc_map = {
        300: SalesforceMoreThanOneRecord,
        400: SalesforceMalformedRequest,
        401: SalesforceExpiredSession,
        403: SalesforceRefusedRequest,
        404: SalesforceResourceNotFound,
    }
    exc_cls = exc_map.get(result.status_code, SalesforceGeneralError)

    raise exc_cls(result.url, result.status_code, name, response_content)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To 'isolate the error message itself' and get towards the Desired Output described, we can import `SalesforceMalformedRequest` and then use `e.content` like this (here in Python 3.5)...

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
from simple_salesforce.exceptions import SalesforceMalformedRequest

sf = Salesforce(...)

try:
    print(sf.query_all("SELECT Id FROM Contactd"))
except SalesforceMalformedRequest as e:
    print(type(e.content))
    print(e.content)
```

... from that we see that the type is `'list'` and the list contains a `dict`; therefore to get the desired string we can use:

```
print(e.content[0]['message'])
```

p.s. In working this out, I also came across this issue on github: [exception_handler provides inconsistent API #215](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce/issues/215)

Answer (score 0):

The API calls return error data that your client application can use to identify and resolve runtime errors. If an error occurs during the invocation of most API calls, then the API provides the following types of error handling:

For errors resulting from badly formed messages, failed authentication, or similar problems, the API returns a SOAP fault message with an associated ExceptionCode.
For most calls, if the error occurs because of a problem specific to the query, the API returns an Error. For example, if a create() request contains more than 200 objects.

When you sign on via the login() call, a new client session begins and a corresponding unique session ID is generated. Sessions expire automatically after a predetermined length of inactivity, which can be configured in Salesforce from Setup by clicking Security Controls. The default is 120 minutes (two hours). If you make an API call, the inactivity timer is reset to zero.

When your session expires, the exception code INVALID_SESSION_ID is returned. If this happens, you must invoke the login() call again.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I think I have reached the point where I have identified the error as mentioned in the second paragraph, but need to isolate just a part of it.